# Can I save my fortress with a wall?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

(Move to the **TL;DR** section if you don't care about the context.)

So I was digging too deep when I found some giant cave spider. I think I was bothering it, since it proceeded to decimate my fledgling military. Once I had managed to calm it down, er, permanently, the tunnel revealed another welcome guest; a forgotten beast. This monster, which apparently took the appearance of a giant grasshopper made of iron and with five or so mouths, then tore right through a door blocking off the mines in my fortress from the rest of the place.

Now, what remains of my military is fighting the beast, but I am sensing their inevitable failure. Thus, I need to enact Operation: Grasshopper Blocker, which consists of me building a wall. However, remembering that the grasshopper could destroy doors, and knowing that giant cave spiders (which I'm sure there are more down there) are building destroyers, I am uncertain whether or not my wall would be enough.

**TL;DR** Are constructed walls (wooden and other) safe from building destroyers?

Followup question: is it possible to cause a cave-in that will permanently close a passage?

Comment: I didn't do any science but i believe wood can catch fire and none magma save stone can melt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, constructed walls are safe from building destroyers, as walls are a type of construction rather than a type of building.

From the [Building Destroyers page](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Building_destroyer) of the DF wiki:

> Constructions (walls, staircase, floors, etc.) are still safe, since they're processed the same way natural terrain is for most situations.

Answer (score 3):

Rave turned answered the primary question. In answer to the follow up, yes a cave-in can permanently seal a tunnel.

Comment: True, but the cave-in must be of natural walls. Constructed walls deconstruct before reaching the floor.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: Note that cast obsidian counts as natural stone, even if produced artificially. Of course, if you can cast and cave in obsidian down a mining shaft on demand, a random forgotten beast probably isn't much threat to you anyway.